# How does BCS scan keep track of BEP20 token holders

Tags: solidity, bsc, bscscan, mycrypto

Is there a function within the contract that needs to return the amount of holders or is it on BSC scan side. I know for Ether scan they keep track of it through transactions but I have done multiple transactions without BSC scan seeing them as a token transaction. They do see it as a contract interaction though. is the problem from within my transaction code which I will put below or is the problem with BSC scan.

transaction code

```
function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) public {
    require(amount <= balances[msg.sender], "Insufficient balance.");
    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balances[receiver] += amount;
    emit Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BSC scan uses the BEP20 Transfer event to keep track of coin holders. Simply add

```
emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
```

Before the return statement assuming that you have the transfer event below somewhere in your contract

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
```